# In C# is it possible to create a model of entities regardless of the database initially?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In C# is it possible to create a model of entities regardless of the database initially. Are there tools to create graphic entities in this way? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's in your question as a tag - entity framework is a good tool for this. You can create classes, that you push later to the database.

Search for "code-first". Google will provide plenty of results I'm sure.

**Edit based on the comment:**

Well, in that case, try this: when you're creating edmx file, pick the second option - empty model.

From its description:

> Creates an empty model as a starting point for visually designing a
>   conceptual model from the toolbox. Classes are generated from the
>   model when the project is compiled. You can specify a database
>   connection later to map the conceptual model to the storage model.

this may be the thing you want then.

Comment: I would like to avoid "code-first". I'm looking for something like model first or EDMX first (without mapping).